# Spring перехват ошибок (404)

Tags: spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

Всем привет. Изучаю Java Web и Spring MVC. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Нужно сделать свою страницу ошибок. Я не до конца понял как эти ошибки отлавливать. Понятно как отлавливать ошибки в контроллере типа ("page/${id}"). Мы ищем инфу по данному id и если такой нет, выбрасываем исключение или тупо редиректим куда нибудь. Тут всё понятно. Но я хочу, что бы это всё делалось не в каждом контроллере, а где то в одном месте и не важно по какому роуту была эта ошибка.
Что то в роде такого. 
Прописать, что для всех исключений (404), мы резолвим такую jsp и передаём в модель то-то и то-то. И вообще пофиг какой роут вызвал эту ошибку.
В общем как то так.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Web построен на сервлетах. Чтобы наиболее полно ответить на ваш вопрос, давайте посмотрим под [DispatcherServlet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java), который в Spring отвечает за обработку всех запросов.

Вот код, который вызывается, если Spring не находит метод контроллера, который должен обрабатывать запрос:

```
protected void noHandlerFound(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    if (pageNotFoundLogger.isWarnEnabled()) {
        pageNotFoundLogger.warn("No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [" + getRequestUri(request) +
                "] in DispatcherServlet with name '" + getServletName() + "'");
    }
    if (this.throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound) {
        throw new NoHandlerFoundException(request.getMethod(), getRequestUri(request),
                new ServletServerHttpRequest(request).getHeaders());
    }
    else {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Из него видно, что:

- Пишется сообщение в лог
- Если установлен флаг `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound`, то бросается исключение [NoHandlerFoundException](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/NoHandlerFoundException.html)
- Если флаг `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` не установлен, то вызывается метод объекта `HttpServletResponse` `sendError()`;

По умолчанию, флаг сброшен `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound = false`, т.е. вызывается метод `sendError()`, и как результат **контейнер сервлетов** переадресует вас на страницу ошибки. Чтобы переопределить эту страницу на собственную, согласно спецификации JEE. вам нужно задать параметр `error-page` в дескрипторе развертывания `web.xml`

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/404</location>
</error-page>
```

Соответственно, нужно создать и метод контроллера, который будет замапен на URL `/404` и вернет нужную страницу.

---

Может случиться так, что вам потребуется выкинуть пользователя на страницу 404 вручную. Глобально это можно сделать через аннотацию `@ControllerAdvice`, действия перечисленные в классе помеченным данной аннотацией являются дефолтными для всех контроллеров.

Создаем собственный класс исключения:

```
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public ResourceNotFoundException() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Ловим это исключение глобально для всех контроллеров, и перекидываем на `/404`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionInterceptor {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleError404(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e)   {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/404");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Соотвественно чтобы выкинуть пользователя на `404` из любого контроллера, просто бросаете это исключение. Передать дополнительный параметры можно просто добавив нужных полей в класс исключения: собственный код ошибки, сообщение и т.д.

---

Теперь когда у нас есть глобальный `@ExceptionHandler` можно вспомнить про флаг `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` и сделать так, что 404 будет обрабатываться только в нем.

Меняем значение флага:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");
    }
}
```

И дописываем в `@ExceptionHandler` перехват соответствующего класса исключений:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ResourceNotFoundException.class, NoHandlerFoundException.class})
    public ModelAndView handleError404(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e)   {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/404");
        return mv;
    }
```

При этом параметры `error-page` обычно все равно стараются оставлять "на всякий пожарный случай" как fallback, чтобы пользователь вдруг не увидел трекстрейс, который Tomcat показывает в своих сообщениях по дефолту.

---

Полезные ссылки на официальные примеры:

- [error-page](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_136_default_error_page)
- [Spring error handling](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Спасибо за такой полный ответ. Но у меня есть ещё один вопрос. Я не использую XML в конфигурации приложения. Как мне вот это ( <error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/404</location>
</error-page> ) сделать через аннотации?